# JavaFX: Disabling default sort in TableView columns

Tags: java, sorting, javafx, javafx-8, tablecolumn

When I click on a table column in a `TableView`, it will alternate from `ascending`, `descending` and `default` (no arrow). How do I make it toggle between just `ascending` and `descending`?

Answer (score 2):

I meddled with many properties from the `TableView` and `TableColumn` and I found my own solution. It is definitely not elegant, and is also not thread-safe, but at least it works, and it's simple.

```
public static final <T> void disableColumnUnsortedOnClick(TableView<T> tableView)
{
    tableView.getSortOrder().addListener(new ListChangeListener<TableColumn<T, ?>>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(
                javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change<? extends TableColumn<T, ?>> c)
        {
            while (c.next())
            {
                if (c.wasRemoved() && c.getRemovedSize() == 1 && !c.wasAdded())
                {
                    final TableColumn<T, ?> removedColumn = c.getRemoved().get(0);

                    removedColumn.getTableView().getSortOrder().add(removedColumn);
                    removedColumn.setSortType(SortType.ASCENDING);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```